# Move all sub-directory content up one level

Tags: shell-script, files, directory

My top level directory contains a bunch of sub-directories:

- `af`
- `ar`
- `ca`
- `cs`
- `da`
- `de`
- `el`
- `en`
- `...` (lots more)

Each of these directories has the exact, same structure. They contain two directories:

- `v2.3.0`
- `v3.0.0`

I need to move all files from `*/v2.3.0/*.php` up a directory, so we go from:

- `af`

  - `v2.3.0`

    - `file1.php`
    - `file2.php`
  - `v3.0.0`

To this:

- `af`

  - `file1.php`
  - `file2.php`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest solution is:

```
for dir in *; do mv "$dir"/v2.3.0/* "$dir"/; done
```

To only move `php` files use:

```
for dir in *; do mv "$dir"/v2.3.0/*php "$dir"/; done
```

And to avoid error messages if you have files (an not only directories) in the top level:

```
for dir in *; do [ -d "$dir" ] && mv "$dir"/v2.3.0/* "$dir"/; done
```

Comment: `for dir in */` also works for restricting loop to directories only.